# Procedure to identify the most significant predictors variables using R when data has tremendous multicollinearity?

Tags: r

I have a database of around 36 predictor variables which I am using to predict a target variable. The target is a categorical variable consisting of three different classes whereas predictor variables include both numeric and categorical variables.

However, data is subject to severe multi-collinearity. I am trying to build a parsimonious logistic regression model so need to reduce the variables. According to VIF values results become counter intuitive as soon as I reduce the number of variables. On the other hand, I am not very sure that PCR can solve the problem as I need inferences from the sensitivity from each variable.

What is the better option to deal with such problem?

Which packages from 'R' I can use?

Will factor analysis solve the problem?

Or can we infer everything from PCR?

Answer (score 0):

You have first to run ANOVA/Kruskall Wallis test to check which variables are well suited for your problem. For 36 variables I don't think you will need PCA, as this will make your model lose some explainability.

Remember that PCA will reduce dimensionality and also explain only part of the data variance. Factor Analysis will generate groups of variables in factors, in case you want to run a segmented logistic regression for each factor of grouped variables.

If you want to build a parsimonious logistic regression, you can apply some regularization so that you can increase the generalization properties of it, instead of reducing number of variables.

You can use the following R packages: caret (logistic regression), ROCR (AUC), ggplot (plot), DMwR (outliers), mice (missing values)

Also, if you want to make a regularization, you can use the following formula:

[image: Lasso]

[image: Ridge]

In this case, you can develop regularization from scratch, without a library, to adjust the inclination of the sigmoid, so that you can correctly classify your classes:

[image: Sigmoid]